# Use BeautifulSoup To Search This HTML and return pairs of data

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

OK, There's this site for a game where this guy has a charged service that uses JavaScript to buy items from the game store that aren't shown in game. However, he doesn't always think things through, so I can see all of the ID's and names and costs of the offers [here](http://view-source:http://wackoscripts.com/offerz12345/showall.php). I want to make my own version of this, but in Python3.x But, it isn't in JSON format, so I assumed I could use bs4, but I have no clue how. How would I use bs4 to search through the formatting tags and return the values in the columns 'Offer Price', 'Item' and 'Offer Id'? The site (not source) is [here](http://wackoscripts.com/offerz12345/showall.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put all the data in a dict and extract what you want:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests


soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://wackoscripts.com/offerz12345/showall.php").content)
table = soup.select_one("table")
cols = [th.text for th in table.select("tr th")]
data = {h:[] for h in cols}
for row in soup.select("table tr + tr"):
    for k,v in zip(cols, (td.text for td in row.find_all("td"))):
        data[k].append(v)

from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(data)
```

You can pull the data you want using the keys or just filter the data as you iterate. If you are sure the order of the columns does not change then just index each row to pull exactly what you want but in case the order changes you can find out the order and get the indexes:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from  operator import itemgetter


soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://wackoscripts.com/offerz12345/showall.php").content)
table = soup.select_one("table")
wanted = {'Offer Price', 'Item', 'Offer Id'}
keys, indexes = zip(*((th.text, i) for i, th in enumerate(table.select("tr th")) if th.text in wanted))
data = {'Offer Price': [], 'Item': [], 'Offer Id': []}
for row in soup.select("table tr + tr"):
    for k, v in zip(keys, (td.text for td in itemgetter(*indexes)(row.find_all("td")))):
        data[k].append(v)
```

That will give you just the three:

```
{'Offer Price': ['1', '2', '20', '5', '2', '3', '10', '3', '50', '2', '1', '8', '14', '2', '1', '99', '49', '1', '25', '3', '1', '1', '2', '2', '5', '1', '2', '15', '2', '9', '1', '1', '10', '1', '3', '59', '69', '1', '149', '1', '2', '1', '1', '14', '15', '1', '1', '19', '1', '1', '11', '4', '2', '4', '2', '7', '20', '2', '69', '3', '3', '15', '2', '9', '1', '25', '10', '30', '19', '2', '129', '19', '15', '8', '15', '1', '15', '3', '2', '1', '2', '2', '3', '7', '2', '3', '1', '3', '49', '3', '50', '49', '5', '19', '1', '19', '2', '1', '39', '199', '3', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '15', '49', '19', '35', '45', '30', '99', '8', '10', '5', '1', '2', '1', '1', '3', '1', '3', '5', '5', '99', '1', '1', '3', '9', '1', '29', '5', '3', '4', '2', '3', '20', '2', '1', '1', '1', '10', '20', '1', '45', '1', '15', '4', '10', '2', '1', '3', '21', '1', '1', '9', '5', '1', '7', '1', '5', '1', '2', '2', '1', '6', '1', '1', '1', '249', '5', '1', '1', '1', '5', '2', '5', '5', '5', '1', '2', '50', '2', '1', '25', '9', '99', '10', '3', '2', '15', '1', '2', '1', '2', '5', '2', '1', '3', '1', '1', '3', '6', '15', '2', '1', '1', '7', '2', '49', '3', '3', '1', '6', '3', '6', '75', '25', '3', '1', '1', '1', '25', '1', '1', '1', '3', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '5', '99', '2', '2', '1', '1', '5', '1', '1', '1', '3', '3', '1', '29', '10', '15', '15', '3', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '49', '1', '15', '75', '9', '5', '3', '10', '1', '29', '3', '1', '2', '2', '1', '2', '6', '1', '2', '3', '3', '5', '249', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '6', '10', '39', '99', '3', '2', '1', '10', '29', '1', '1', '2', '29', '9', '50', '19', '1', '149', '8', '1', '1', '5', '40', '1', '9', '1', '3', '1', '40', '5', '1', '99', '1', '4', '1', '2', '1', '5', '10', '5', '1', '1', '5', '1', '1', '1', '4', '10', '15', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '19', '1', '2', '3', '5', '149', '5', '5', '1', '2', '3', '1', '10', '10', '25', '1', '1', '699', '149', '20', '10', '9', '1', '3', '7', '1', '5', '10', '2', '15', '35', '10', '29', '5', '1', '5', '1', '1', '9', '2', '1', '449', '7', '149', '25', '1', '9', '10', '7', '1', '2', '2', '1', '2', '2', '1', '1', '2', '29', '1', '1', '3', '5', '9', '9', '1', '1', '1', '15', '1', '1', '17', '2', '1', '4', '1', '45', '2', '2', '2', '99', '2', '1', '3', '1', '2', '499', '25', '9', '3', '1', '5', '1', '1', '5', '5', '2', '2', '4', '39', '5', '3', '9', '5', '5', '1', '9', '10', '1', '1', '75', '5', '3', '1', '49', '3', '2', '4', '1', '9', '3', '1', '2', '5', '50', '60', '29', '3', '2', '3', '2', '35', '25', '10', '1', '1', '4', '15', '10', '15', '10', '5', '19', '30', '7', '10', '29', '25', '3', '25', '25', '15', '5', '6', '5', '1', '2', '4', '1', '1', '19', '1', '1', '1', '5', '1', '5'], 'Item': ['ConfigurableChest3750', 'ConfigurableChest3705', 'ConfigurableChest3743', 'ConfigurableChest3706', 'ConfigurableChest3730', 'ConfigurableChest3742', 'ConfigurableChest3704', 'AbyssalRavager1000TroopPrizeItem', 'ConfigurableChest3098', 'ConfigurableChest3228', 'ConfigurableChest1784', 'ConfigurableChest3024', 'ConfigurableChest1771', 'ConfigurableChest3215', 'ConfigurableChest3280', 'LeviathanDragonArmorChest', 'ConfigurableChest2655', 'LeviathanDragonItem', 'LeviathanDragonInstantUpgrade', 'ConfigurableChest2524', 'ConfigurableChest2507', 'AdvancedMasonryTools', 'ConfigurableChest299', 'ConfigurableChest3492', 'ConfigurableChest1502', 'ConfigurableChest2073', 'AncestralSeal', 'ConfigurableChest2458', 'ConfigurableChest2792', 'AncestralSealPortfolio', 'ConfigurableChest3306', 'ConfigurableChest2116', 'ArmisticeAgreement', 'ConfigurableChest2267', 'ConfigurableChest3392', 'AscendancyGrant', 'ConfigurableChest3660', 'ConfigurableChest3519', 'SdArmor004U', 'ConfigurableChest3428', 'ConfigurableChest2457', 'ConfigurableChest3530', 'ConfigurableChest1872', 'ConfigurableChest1754', 'ConfigurableChest2144', 'ConfigurableChest3493', 'BetterEstateGrant', 'ConfigurableChest2460', 'BetterHomeGrant', 'ConfigurableChest1429', 'ConfigurableChest2080', 'ConfigurableChest1241', 'ConfigurableChest3557', 'ConfigurableChest2213', 'ConfigurableChest1901', 'ConfigurableChest3199', 'Blast', 'ConfigurableChest3443', 'Blitz', 'BlueEnergy250K', 'BluePowder', 'Bolt', 'ConfigurableChest1690', 'ConfigurableChest2103', 'ConfigurableChest1787', 'ConfigurableChest1516', 'ConfigurableChest1854', 'ConfigurableChest1801', 'ConfigurableChest1716', 'ConfigurableChest3465', 'ConfigurableChest2480', 'ConfigurableChest1622', 'Bore', 'Bounce', 'Food10M', 'ConfigurableChest3518', 'ConfigurableChest2738', 'ConfigurableChest220', 'ConfigurableChest3476', 'ConfigurableChest3665', 'ConfigurableChest2262', 'ConfigurableChest2759', 'CelestialDragonKey', 'ConfigurableChest3415', 'ConfigurableChest1233', 'ChartedWarpDevice', 'ConfigurableChest3140', 'ConfigurableChest3614', 'ChronoDragonArk', 'ConfigurableChest989', 'ChronoDragonSprocket', 'TimeTrickstersBag', 'ConfigurableChest1161', 'ConfigurableChest1637', 'ConfigurableChest1701', 'ColossusDragonEgg', 'CompletionGrant', 'ConfigurableChest2922', 'ConfigurableChest1770', 'ConfigurableChest2744', 'ConfigurableChest2509', 'ConfigurableChest3031', 'ConfigurableChest2184', 'ConfigurableChest2319', 'ConfigurableChest1432', 'ConfigurableChest3232', 'ConfigurableChest3307', 'ConfigurableChest2264', 'ConfigurableChest2268', 'ConfigurableChest2274', 'ConfigurableChest2269', 'ConfigurableChest2275', 'ConfigurableChest2280', 'ConfigurableChest2286', 'ConfigurableChest1840', 'DarkWarpDevice', 'ConfigurableChest3379', 'ConfigurableChest1924', 'ConfigurableChest3601', 'ConfigurableChest2219', 'ConfigurableChest3591', 'ConfigurableChest2390', 'ConfigurableChest3635', 'ConfigurableChest2803', 'ConfigurableChest2979', 'DominionGrant', 'ConfigurableChest3067', 'ConfigurableChest2820', 'ConfigurableChest2490', 'ConfigurableChest1941', 'DoubleTaxWeekDeclaration', 'ConfigurableChest3564', 'DraconicSeal', 'ConfigurableChest1664', 'FortunasArcadeToken', 'ConfigurableChest1174', 'ConfigurableChest3065', 'ConfigurableChest2199', 'ElderDragonSeal', 'ConfigurableChest2354', 'ConfigurableChest2233', 'ConfigurableChest2834', 'ConfigurableChest2170', 'ElixirOfKratosEpic', 'ElixirOfKratosRare', 'ConfigurableChest2935', 'ConfigurableChest2246', 'ConfigurableChest3181', 'EnchantedTowerSchematic', 'ConfigurableChest2637', 'ConfigurableChest2802', 'ConfigurableChest2125', 'ConfigurableChest2924', 'ConfigurableChest709', 'ConfigurableChest2760', 'ConfigurableChest2290', 'ConfigurableChest2378', 'ConfigurableChest1394', 'ConfigurableChest1265', 'ConfigurableChest1865', 'ConfigurableChest1212', 'ConfigurableChest1731', 'ConfigurableChest2413', 'ConfigurableChest3283', 'ConfigurableChest3305', 'ConfigurableChest1453', 'ConfigurableChest2487', 'ConfigurableChest1993', 'ConfigurableChest3192', 'ConfigurableChest2671', 'ConfigurableChest3594', 'ConfigurableChest3528', 'ConfigurableChest123', 'ConfigurableChest3529', 'ConfigurableChest2189', 'ConfigurableChest3030', 'ConfigurableChest1460', 'ConfigurableChest3404', 'Godspeed', 'ConfigurableChest2624', 'ConfigurableChest3661', 'ConfigurableChest3590', 'ConfigurableChest2384', 'ConfigurableChest2234', 'ConfigurableChest2235', 'GreatDragonItem', 'GreatDragonInstantUpgrade2', 'GreatDragonInstantUpgrade', 'WndArmor003U', 'ConfigurableChest3265', 'ConfigurableChest1629', 'ConfigurableChest3435', 'HarpoonPart', 'ConfigurableChest1896', 'ConfigurableChest3326', 'ConfigurableChest2888', 'ConfigurableChest2117', 'ConfigurableChest3624', 'ConfigurableChest1528', 'ConfigurableChest3112', 'ConfigurableChest2669', 'ConfigurableChest1368', 'ConfigurableChest2548', 'ConfigurableChest1656', 'ConfigurableChest3386', 'ConfigurableChest260', 'ConfigurableChest3663', 'ConfigurableChest2677', 'ConfigurableChest2244', 'ConfigurableChest2762', 'Jump', 'ConfigurableChest3227', 'ConfigurableChest3434', 'ExplorationOrders', 'ConfigurableChest2312', 'ConfigurableChest2576', 'ConfigurableChest810', 'Leap', 'ConfigurableChest957', 'LegendaryObscuraDragonEgg1', 'ConfigurableChest2506', 'ConfigurableChest3448', 'ConfigurableChest2344', 'LineageSeal', 'ConfigurableChest2670', 'ConfigurableChest2190', 'ConfigurableChest1221', 'ConfigurableChest2072', 'ConfigurableChest1277', 'ConfigurableChest2133', 'ConfigurableChest2542', 'ConfigurableChest2245', 'ConfigurableChest1246', 'ConfigurableChest2198', 'ConfigurableChest2212', 'ConfigurableChest3405', 'ConfigurableChest2362', 'LunaComet', 'LunaCrescent', 'LunaMeteorite', 'ConfigurableChest2488', 'LunaRock', 'ConfigurableChest3427', 'ConfigurableChest2351', 'ConfigurableChest1430', 'ConfigurableChest2132', 'ConfigurableChest1859', 'ConfigurableChest2353', 'ConfigurableChest2013', 'ConfigurableChest1759', 'MassNullifier', 'ConfigurableChest2630', 'ConfigurableChest1916', 'AdditionalCapacity5', 'MasterworkTowerSchematic', 'ConfigurableChest2833', 'ConfigurableChest1727', 'ConfigurableChest2415', 'ConfigurableChest1131', 'SwampDragonItem2', 'ConfigurableChest2263', 'ConfigurableChest1431', 'ConfigurableChest2169', 'ConfigurableChest2374', 'ConfigurableChest2331', 'ConfigurableChest2240', 'ConfigurableChest2414', 'ConfigurableChest1287', 'ConfigurableChest1311', 'MysticMasonryTools', 'MysticTowerSchematic', 'ConfigurableChest3064', 'ConfigurableChest2747', 'ConfigurableChest2892', 'ConfigurableChest1146', 'ConfigurableChest3154', 'NomadicRecruits', 'ConfigurableChest2066', 'ConfigurableChest2603', 'ConfigurableChest1483', 'ConfigurableChest2764', 'ConfigurableChest3459', 'OlympianTincture', 'OlympianTincture14', 'OlympianTincture15', 'ConfigurableChest2690', 'ConfigurableChest3241', 'ConfigurableChest2252', 'ConfigurableChest2372', 'ConfigurableChest2765', 'ConfigurableChest2661', 'ConfigurableChest1800', 'ConfigurableChest2162', 'ConfigurableChest2636', 'ConfigurableChest2691', 'PhilosophersStone', 'ConfigurableChest1638', 'ConfigurableChest2995', 'ConfigurableChest3014', 'ConfigurableChest2321', 'ConfigurableChest2211', 'ConfigurableChest2827', 'ConfigurableChest2236', 'ConfigurableChest2302', 'ConfigurableChest2318', 'ConfigurableChest2303', 'ConfigurableChest2937', 'ConfigurableChest3359', 'ConfigurableChest3021', 'ConfigurableChest2077', 'ConfigurableChest3333', 'ConfigurableChest2217', 'ConfigurableChest3033', 'ConfigurableChest3099', 'ConfigurableChest3165', 'GreatDragonFamiliar', 'ConfigurableChest3039', 'ConfigurableChest3593', 'ConfigurableChest3319', 'ConfigurableChest1899', 'ConfigurableChest829', 'ConfigurableChest3304', 'ConfigurableChest2114', 'ConfigurableChest2350', 'RoyalDragonKey', 'ConfigurableChest2486', 'ConfigurableChest2165', 'ConfigurableChest3366', 'ConfigurableChest623', 'SacredRations', 'SacredShields', 'ConfigurableChest2270', 'ConfigurableChest3511', 'ConfigurableChest262', 'ConfigurableChest3174', 'ConfigurableChest1623', 'ConfigurableChest1758', 'ConfigurableChest1803', 'ConfigurableChest2612', 'ConfigurableChest1725', 'ConfigurableChest1757', 'ConfigurableChest781', 'ConfigurableChest2559', 'ConfigurableChest2610', 'ConfigurableChest2916', 'BellPart', 'ConfigurableChest1700', 'Skip', 'ConfigurableChest1732', 'ConfigurableChest1391', 'ConfigurableChest2472', 'ConfigurableChest1240', 'SolarNectar', 'ConfigurableChest2273', 'ConfigurableChest1845', 'ConfigurableChest3577', 'ConfigurableChest3378', 'ConfigurableChest3193', 'SpectralSeal', 'ConfigurableChest3166', 'ConfigurableChest2360', 'ConfigurableChest2515', 'ConfigurableChest2376', 'ConfigurableChest2478', 'CaveDragonEgg', 'CaveDragonInstantUpgrade', 'SteelshardFlowstone', 'ConfigurableChest2361', 'SteelshardPillar', 'SteelshardRosette', 'ConfigurableChest3240', 'StormOffering', 'StormSacrifice', 'ConfigurableChest3520', 'StrengthOfHephaestusElite', 'StrengthOfHephaestusEpic', 'StrengthOfHephaestusSuperRare', 'StygianSeal', 'ConfigurableChest3697', 'ConfigurableChest2753', 'ConfigurableChest2078', 'ConfigurableChest2004', 'ConfigurableChest3168', 'SupremeDragonKey', 'ConfigurableChest3636', 'ConfigurableChest3377', 'ConfigurableChest3643', 'ConfigurableChest3589', 'TempestDragonEgg', 'TempestFury', 'ConfigurableChest3666', 'TestroniusDeluxe', 'TestroniusInfusion', 'TestroniusPowder', 'ConfigurableChest3111', 'ConfigurableChest2523', 'ConfigurableChest3139', 'ConfigurableChest2343', 'ConfigurableChest2985', 'ConfigurableChest3281', 'ConfigurableChest2309', 'ConfigurableChest2310', 'ConfigurableChest2575', 'ConfigurableChest2266', 'ConfigurableChest2118', 'ConfigurableChest1823', 'ConfigurableChest2164', 'ConfigurableChest2221', 'ConfigurableChest2271', 'ConfigurableChest2352', 'ConfigurableChest2819', 'ConfigurableChest1756', 'ConfigurableChest2938', 'ConfigurableChest2220', 'ConfigurableChest2391', 'ConfigurableChest2151', 'ConfigurableChest3622', 'ConfigurableChest2522', 'ConfigurableChest2863', 'ConfigurableChest2531', 'ConfigurableChest1794', 'ConfigurableChest1797', 'ConfigurableChest1861', 'ConfigurableChest3615', 'ConfigurableChest2717', 'LeviathanDragonFamiliar', 'ConfigurableChest3282', 'ConfigurableChest2835', 'ConfigurableChest2163', 'ConfigurableChest2232', 'ConfigurableChest2442', 'ConfigurableChest2320', 'CaveDragonFamiliar', 'ConfigurableChest1733', 'ConfigurableChest2706', 'ConfigurableChest3138', 'ConfigurableChest2508', 'ConfigurableChest3477', 'ConfigurableChest2243', 'ConfigurableChest2200', 'ConfigurableChest925', 'ConfigurableChest2944', 'ConfigurableChest1513', 'ConfigurableChest2197', 'ConfigurableChest2763', 'TokenOfDivinity', 'ConfigurableChest1482', 'TranceMarchElixir', 'ConfigurableChest1788', 'ConfigurableChest947', 'ConfigurableChest2936', 'ConfigurableChest1989', 'ConfigurableChest2012', 'ConfigurableChest3239', 'ConfigurableChest1574', 'ConfigurableChest2505', 'ConfigurableChest3684', 'ConfigurableChest1890', 'ConfigurableChest2913', 'GdVictoryArmorU', 'ConfigurableChest2459', 'ConfigurableChest1197', 'ConfigurableChest2041', 'ConfigurableChest2287', 'ConfigurableChest2115', 'ConfigurableChest2901', 'ConfigurableChest2289', 'ConfigurableChest2638', 'ConfigurableChest2060', 'ConfigurableChest2471', 'ConfigurableChest2479', 'ConfigurableChest2504', 'ConfigurableChest2028', 'ConfigurableChest3066', 'ConfigurableChest1117', 'ConfigurableChest1044', 'ConfigurableChest1907', 'ConfigurableChest1898', 'VenomTrapPart', 'ConfigurableChest3020', 'ConfigurableChest532', 'VulcansBlessingCommon', 'VulcansBlessing14Common', 'VulcansBlessing17Elite', 'VulcansBlessing18Elite', 'VulcansBlessingEpic', 'VulcansBlessingRare', 'VulcansBlessing14Rare', 'VulcansBlessing15Rare', 'VulcansBlessing18Rare', 'VulcansBlessingSuperRare', 'VulcansBlessing14SuperRare', 'VulcansBlessing17SuperRare', 'VulcansBlessingUncommon', 'VulcansBlessing14Uncommon', 'VulcansBlessing18Uncommon', 'VulcansBlessing19Uncommon', 'ConfigurableChest2498', 'ConfigurableChest1988', 'ConfigurableChest3623', 'ConfigurableChest2011', 'ConfigurableChest1428', 'ConfigurableChest2649', 'ConfigurableChest3570', 'ConfigurableChest2746', 'ConfigurableChest2079', 'ConfigurableChest2733', 'ConfigurableChest2031', 'ConfigurableChest1982', 'ConfigurableChest2409', 'ConfigurableChest3337', 'ConfigurableChest3651'], 'Offer Id': ['10841', '10829', '10990', '10845', '10929', '10954', '10828', '8955', '9194', '9549', '7736', '9260', '6816', '9521', '9639', '8257', '8961', '9992', '9522', '8332', '7754', '7654', '6267', '10227', '7755', '8337', '9171', '7660', '8608', '9181', '9698', '7767', '6705', '7092', '10441', '10738', '10754', '10277', '7025', '10055', '7759', '10355', '6422', '6978', '7528', '10221', '9275', '9245', '9219', '8511', '6556', '7690', '10427', '6699', '6607', '9485', '7834', '10094', '9182', '6493', '6276', '9205', '7408', '7770', '7544', '7653', '7297', '6742', '7707', '10146', '7531', '7673', '9289', '9148', '9416', '10281', '8557', '6825', '10179', '10735', '8298', '9278', '9758', '10018', '7371', '7728', '9333', '10647', '6558', '6960', '7411', '8997', '6996', '6579', '7761', '7744', '8276', '9146', '7748', '9163', '9263', '9258', '7042', '7832', '7828', '9576', '9741', '6623', '6654', '6744', '6669', '6673', '6728', '6767', '6540', '6800', '9940', '6785', '10604', '6371', '10541', '8327', '10661', '9538', '9169', '9343', '9965', '9038', '8667', '7697', '7004', '10449', '10799', '6711', '8303', '6710', '9273', '7307', '7286', '7009', '8267', '9035', '6324', '10573', '8290', '9299', '6605', '9436', '6367', '8308', '9256', '6794', '9269', '6539', '8348', '8998', '7670', '6784', '7083', '7699', '6548', '7772', '9285', '9648', '9719', '7369', '7784', '6642', '9435', '8882', '10560', '10657', '7749', '10335', '8576', '9227', '7473', '10000', '7507', '8116', '10751', '10495', '7825', '6500', '7729', '7362', '10008', '7848', '7136', '9614', '6530', '10071', '9286', '6741', '9817', '9123', '6521', '10633', '6893', '9290', '8564', '7646', '8305', '7624', '9948', '8214', '10831', '8942', '7678', '9259', '9482', '10340', '10078', '9246', '8253', '7809', '6826', '6645', '7278', '10871', '7838', '10129', '7614', '9271', '8551', '7737', '7683', '9122', '7040', '8586', '9191', '7826', '6790', '7668', '8602', '9991', '7212', '8339', '10267', '7609', '7762', '6282', '10037', '9217', '7514', '7777', '6772', '7723', '8264', '6534', '6506', '8972', '7377', '7836', '6351', '9010', '6536', '7818', '7468', '7230', '7769', '7580', '7644', '8328', '8588', '8347', '7647', '6479', '6789', '10271', '9173', '9233', '8625', '9071', '6447', '9355', '6297', '6798', '8568', '6318', '8611', '10152', '9022', '9752', '10424', '8192', '9543', '9151', '8507', '9229', '9135', '6854', '7787', '8180', '8193', '8610', '6602', '9272', '9294', '7604', '7827', '9274', '9255', '7641', '7773', '7209', '9283', '9906', '9199', '6518', '9884', '7526', '9268', '9477', '9399', '7698', '9279', '10549', '9729', '7365', '6911', '9699', '6538', '7270', '9264', '7512', '6352', '9892', '6632', '6743', '7622', '8598', '10268', '7242', '9415', '7620', '7537', '7463', '8127', '6533', '7485', '6478', '9214', '8578', '9198', '6717', '6262', '9641', '6485', '7685', '7524', '6690', '9239', '7632', '6541', '10486', '9937', '9881', '9925', '10210', '7015', '8329', '7240', '8326', '8178', '10465', '6323', '7708', '9452', '8938', '9530', '10482', '10763', '10302', '9666', '10177', '10126', '10606', '10819', '8962', '7141', '7803', '9455', '6368', '10669', '9929', '10696', '10784', '10814', '10401', '10743', '6909', '9444', '6689', '9242', '8238', '9351', '8235', '9216', '9643', '6827', '7837', '7771', '6805', '7750', '9270', '7655', '6734', '7822', '7594', '9228', '7805', '9235', '7745', '8307', '6732', '10620', '7766', '9236', '7757', '6408', '6606', '6782', '10654', '8954', '9254', '9644', '9213', '8279', '8310', '7619', '6904', '10282', '8185', '8615', '9311', '8258', '10206', '6682', '6319', '7781', '9195', '8601', '6350', '9247', '6258', '7804', '6288', '9108', '7611', '9304', '6698', '8993', '9565', '8256', '7782', '10776', '6570', '9251', '7273', '8174', '6737', '6544', '6878', '7394', '9262', '7351', '8335', '6510', '7635', '7478', '7793', '6487', '9287', '6564', '6442', '7560', '6450', '7082', '9168', '7638', '6301', '7166', '9144', '9824', '10358', '8205', '7824', '8282', '10045', '8206', '7372', '9241', '8247', '7202', '9749', '10646', '7740', '6561', '10612', '9238', '6674', '8306', '10451', '8621', '6617', '9277', '9276', '7677', '7587', '10164', '10800']}
```

Answer (score 1):

The markup is quite convenient to use [`pandas.read_html()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) to read the HTML table into the *dataframe*. Complete working example:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "http://wackoscripts.com/offerz12345/showall.php"
response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'})
df = pd.read_html(response.content)
print(df)
```

[`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) is used to download the page content.

Comment: It said I needed lxml, so I did pip install lxml, but I got this: ```Command "c:\users\other\desktop\python3.5.2\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Other\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-eywbicns\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Other\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-hjrmjmxt-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Other\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-eywbicns\lxml\```